# Issue with tk console when using OpenSSH

Tags: user-interface, console, tcl, tk-toolkit, activetcl

I wrote a TCL/TK based application with GUI to manage and do various operations, When using spawn telnet normally everything happening shows up in the console using
`catch {console show}` but if I use openSSH or plink to connect to the equipment, The console doesn't show anything and I dont know how to fix it

Thanks alot upfront :P

Comment: Please be way more detailed. The word `spawn` hints you're using the `expect` package for automation. Is it correct? Then what's the connection with the console? I mean, what do you expect? Do you expect that whatever command you run using some remoting protocol (be it telnet or SSH) automatically gets its standard streams connected to the Tk's graphical console (available only on Windows, IIRC), and this does not happen?

Comment: No the script works perfectly fine but I don't see what it's doing in the TK console if I use spawn ssh.exe (OpenSSH), If I use spawn telnet it works fine and I can see the script running in console to monitor what it's doing

Comment: Ah, that's probably a “real” stdio/“fake” stdio problem (the Tk `console` merely simulates stdio; it doesn't use an OS file handle). Don't know Expect well enough to suggest how to work around it, but I'm sure it can be done as there have been examples of using Expect and Tk to create a GUI terminal program and this is the sort of thing you'd want to adapt.